# Mac crashing with "critical" hardware error macOS 11

Tags: macos

My MacBook Air 2017 running macOS 11 crashed in the middle of update. Now every time when I do anything I get an error "critical system error occurred". My MBA pretty much disabled.

Comment: macOS 10.11.x - El Capitan?

Comment: Or do you mean MacOs 11 Big Sur? Can you boot to Recovery Mode?  (Hold Command R at boot)

Comment: When I try to boot inside Recovery OS cannot load system. Yeah